# iOS enterprise distribution account renew before expiration

Tags: ios, ios-enterprise, iosdeployment

If i renew my In House/Enterprise Membership licence before expiration(It is expiring on 2nd April 2018 but renewed it yesterday), do i need to re-build my apps again and distribute again(my iOS provisioning profile for iOS distribution expiring on 16 feb 2019).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you must do nothing. Just pay